# Hiding a subview from another subview class

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

I am very new to Cocoa and Ojective-C.  "Learning as you go is my philosophy".  This is my first Cocoa project.

Basically, I used Interface Builder to create a main NSView (let's call it MainView), in it I have two sub-NSView (let's call it ViewNS1 and ViewNS2).  And ViewNS1 is bound view1 class and ViewNS2 is bound to view2 class.

When I click on ViewNS1, I would like hide the ViewNS2 view.  In my view1 class view1.m file, I have this [viewNS2 setHidden:YES] in my - (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)event.  There was no error when running but it does not work.  I can however successfully do a [viewNS2 setHidden:YES] from within my MainView.m and it worked fine.  Also if I do a [viewNS1 setHidden:YES] from the view1.m then it will hide its own view.

I think this is very fundamental and basic...  But could not find a solution.

"A teaching moment" anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ViewNS1`'s *controller* should react to the click and hide `ViewNS2`. `ViewNS1` doesn't need to have any direct knowledge of `ViewNS2` -- that is the whole point of the MVC pattern, to eliminate these dependencies and reduce coupling.

Comment: I original asked the question in Nov '10.  Now I have gained some experiment with Objective-c, so yours r right answer!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer from another posting on this site.  This is my solution:
I use this [self.superview hideViews1] in my mouseDown event in view1.m.  Where hideViews1 is a method from MainView.m that will hide all views that are needed to be hidden, [viewNS2 setHidden:YES] etc.

Comment: This creates a circular dependency since MainView and ViewNS1 know about each other. Circular dependencies are bad since they make your code harder to maintain and understand. Consider refactoring to use the view controller instead, which would be following the MVC pattern.

Comment: yeah, that MVC thing I still need to learn.  Thanks for your comments!